# /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -q [^0-9] does not always work as expected

Tags: unix, grep, ksh

I have a Unix ksh script that has been in daily use for years (kicked off at night by the crontab).  Recently one function in the script is behaving erratically as never happened before.  I tried various ways to find out why, but have no success.

The function validates an input string, which is supposed to be a string of 10 numeric characters.  The function checks if the string length is 10, and whether it contains any non-numeric characters:

```sh
#! /bin/ksh

# The function:
is_valid_id () {
   # Takes one argument, which is the ID being tested.
   if [[ $(print ${#1}) -ne 10 ]] || print "$1" | /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -q [^0-9] ; then
      return 1
   else
      return 0
   fi
}

cat $input_file | while read line ; do
   id=$(print $line | awk -F: '{print $5}')
   # Calling the function:
   is_valid_id $id
   stat=$?
   if [[ $stat -eq 1 ]] ; then
      print "The ID $id is invalid.  Request rejected.\n" >> $ERRLOG
      continue
   else
      ...
   fi
done
```

The problem with the function is that, every night, out of scores or hundreds of requests, it finds the IDs in several requests as invalid.  I visually inspected the input data and found that all the "invalid" IDs are actually strings of 10 numeric characters as should be.  This error seems to be random, because it happens with only some of the requests.  However, while the rejected requests persistently come back, it is consistently the same IDs that are picked out as invalid day after day.

I did the following:

1. The Unix machine has been running for almost a year, therefore might need to be refreshed.  The system admin to reboot the machine at my request.  But the problem persists after the reboot.
2. I manually ran exactly the same two tests in the function, at command prompt, and the IDs that have been found invalid at night are all valid.
3. I know the same commands may behave differently invoked manually or in a script.  To see how the function behaves in script, the above code excerpt is the small script I ran to reproduce the problem.  And indeed, some (though not all) of the IDs found to be invalid at night are also found invalid by the small trouble-shooting script.
4. I then modified that troubleshooting script to run the two tests one at a time, and found it is the `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -q [^0-9]` test that erroneously finds some of the ID as containing non-numeric character(s).  Well, the IDs are all numeric characters, at least visually.
5. I checked if there is any problem with the xpg4 grep command file (`ls -l /usr/xpg4/bin/grep`),  to see if it is put there recently.  But its timestamp is year 2005 (this machine runs Solaris 10).
6. Knowing that the data comes from a central ERP system, to which data entry is performed from different locations using all kinds of various terminal machines running all kinds of possible operating systems that support various character sets and encodings.  The ERP system simply allows them.  But can characters from other encodings visually appear as numeric characters but the encoded values are not as the `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` command expects to be on our Unix machine?  I tried the `od` (octal dump) command but it does not help me much as I am not familiar with it.  Maybe I need to know more about `od` for solving this problem.

My temporary work-around is omitting the `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -q [^0-9]` test.  But the problem has not been solved.  What can I try next?

Comment: Please give us an actual example of an ID that is incorrectly handled. Other than that, turn on `set -x` and maybe the debug output will show what's wrong.

Comment: PS: `grep -q [^0-9]` should be `grep -q '[^0-9]'`. If you have in the CWD a file named `a` (or any non-numeric one letter name), you'd be surprised due to shell globbing. The `set -x` suggested above would catch this immediately.

Comment: on a failure run `od -c <<< "${1}"` to see if you have any non-numeric characters in the string (a trailing `\n` is normal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validity test function happens to be more complicated than it should be. E.g. why do you use a command substitution with `print` for `${#1}`? Why don't you use `${#1}` directly? Next, forking grep to test for a non-number is a slow and expensive operation. What about this equivalent function, 100% POSIX and blazingly fast:

```sh
is_valid_id () {
   # Takes one argument, which is the ID being tested.

   if test ${#1} -ne 10; then
      return 1                  # ID length not exactly 10.
   fi
   case $1 in
     (*[!0-9]*) return 1;;      # ID contains a non-digit.
     (*)        return 0;;      # ID is exactly 10 digits.
   esac
}
```

Or even more simple, if you don't mind repeating yourself:

```sh
is_valid_id () {
   # Takes one argument, which is the ID being tested.
   case $1 in
     ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])   # 10 digits.
       return 0;;
     (*)
       return 1;;
   esac
}
```

This also avoids your unquoted use of a `grep` pattern, which is error-prone in the presence of one-character file names. Does this work better?

Comment: Thank you very much Jens.  The problem turns out to be the regular expression that is not quoted.  In the test script, after adding quotes to the [^0-9] expression, the problem is gone.

The function being called executes in a subshell, which the set -x debugging mode does not seem to reach.  It only shows that the function returned 1, without showing how the function is executed in the subshell.

Comment: Anyway, with the problem found, I will add back the omitted /usr/xpg4/bin/grep to the function and let it run for some time to give proof that the unquoted expression was indded the sause of the error.  And then I will replace the function with the second version you provided, which tests two things in one step without involving an external command file.

Comment: @newman Good to hear it solved your problem. Your code replacement strategy is certainly sound. The next step on Stackoverflow is to accept the answer that helped you best by clicking the check mark near the vote counts. Out of curiosity, what is the one character file name in the cron job user's directory?

Comment: There isn't a one-character file name involved.  The name of the script with the problem function in it is not one-character.  It is not in crontab but is called by another script in the crontab.  The name of the calling script is not one-character either.  I am aware of the difference between regex and globbing, which can be easily mixed up and become confusing for that.  But I do not know how it would be dramatic with a one-character file name.

Comment: @newman The nesting level of scripts calling scripts does not matter. You can demonstrate the problem with `echo [^0-9]`. You expect this to output `[^0-9]`, right? Now `touch a; echo [^0-9]`. This outputs `a`. So used as a grep pattern you can see that instead of grepping for a digit, it greps for the letter a. Which is obviously not what you expect your script to do.

Comment: Thank you Jens for sharing. I am a ksh user, not familiar with bash. I tried and it turns out what you described is the behavior of bash, not ksh. In bash `echo [^0-9]` returns single-character file names; `echo m*` returns all file names that start with m; `echo [^0-9]*` returns all file names that start with a non-numeric character. It's interesting that in bash `echo` also does the work of `ls`.